# How do I iterate through this object properly AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So I've made a object array(?) like this:

```
public var object:Object = 
{
    "part1" : {
        "text" : "Your name is Richard, a 20-something year old construction worker who just returned home from a night of heavy drinking. The clock above your sofa reads 9:37PM. What do you do?",
        "choices" : {
            "response1" : {
                "text" : "Go to sleep", 
                "nextPart" : "part2" 
            },
            "response2" : {
                "text" : "Watch TV",
                "nextPart" : "part3" 
            }
        }
    },
    "part2" : {
        "text" : "You go to sleep. You are awoken by the sound of glass smashing outside your house. The time on your alarm reads 12:30AM",
        "nextPart" : "part3"
    },
    "part3" : {
        "text" : "You sit down and start watching TV. All channels seem to be the same thing, a breaking news report. You tune in.",
        "nextPart" : "part4"
    },
    "part4" : 
        {
            "text" : "The reporter on the screen has a panicked tone, which you seem to think is unprofessional. You are horrified by what you hear; people are turning into disgusting deformed mutants that possess super human abilities. You are interrupted by someone jumping through your front window. How rude.",
            "nextPart" : "part5"
        },
    "part5" : {
        "text" : "You get up from your sofa and go towards the dickhead who jumped through your window. He turns out to be a dead body that was acutally thrown through the window. He's missing an eye and large portion of his skull. You look up to see a disfigured man standing outside your window. His face has swollen to 3x it's original size and covers his neck. He climbs through your window. You noticed acidic green liquid dripping from orifices on his face.",
        "nextPart" : "part6"
    }
}
```

I need to iterate through the choices of `part1`.

I am currently trying this:

```
for (var s:String in object[curPart]["choices"]) i++
{
    trace(i)
    textFinished = false
    var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',15,0xFFFFFF);
    txt.text = String(i)
    txt.filters = [stroke];
    txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    txt.selectable = false;
    txt.width = 400
    txt.height = 25
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();
    btn.mouseChildren = false;
    btn.addChild(txt); 
    btn.buttonMode = true;
    btn.x = stage.stageWidth / 10
    btn.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - 50 * (i * .5)
    btn.name = "part" + String((Number(Number(curPart.substring(4))+1) + (i+1)))
    buttonHolder.addChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener(
        MouseEvent.CLICK, 
        function m(zen:MouseEvent):void // when button is clicked 
        {
            //trace(buttonHolder.numChildren)
            //choice(zen.currentTarget.name,buttonHolder);
        } 
    )

    // Each button is put in the list,
    // to be able to work with the button after
}
```

but I only get 1 textfield and that says 2 (even though there should be 2 text fields that go 1, 2)

Comment: please show your code here instead of somewhere else that may go away in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
for (var s:String in object[curPart]["choices"]) i++
```

The `i++` is executed in the `for`-loop, everything else is just run once.
Move `i++` inside the braces of your loop, and everything will work fine.

```
for (var s:String in object[curPart]["choices"])
{
    i++; // Increase counter here
    trace(i)
    textFinished = false
    var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',15,0xFFFFFF);
    txt.text = String(i)
    txt.filters = [stroke];
    txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    txt.selectable = false;
    txt.width = 400
    txt.height = 25
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();
    btn.mouseChildren = false;
    btn.addChild(txt); 
    btn.buttonMode = true;
    btn.x = stage.stageWidth / 10
    btn.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - 50 * (i * .5)
    btn.name = "part" + String((Number(Number(curPart.substring(4))+1) + (i+1)))
    buttonHolder.addChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener(
        MouseEvent.CLICK, 
        function m(zen:MouseEvent):void // when button is clicked 
        {
            //trace(buttonHolder.numChildren)
            //choice(zen.currentTarget.name,buttonHolder);
        } 
    )

    // Each button is put in the list,
    // to be able to work with the button after
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you've posted, I'd hazard a guess, that you need to implement few loops:

1. A loop through the "main" **object**, which consists of "part objects".
2. A loop through the each of the "part objects"

Here what I mean:

```
var object:Object = 
{
    "part1" : {
        "text" : "Your name is Richard, a 20-something year old construction worker who just returned home from a night of heavy drinking. The clock above your sofa reads 9:37PM. What do you do?",
        "choices" : {
            "response1" : {
                "text" : "Go to sleep", 
                "nextPart" : "part2" 
            },
            "response2" : {
                "text" : "Watch TV",
                "nextPart" : "part3" 
            }
        }
    },
    "part2" : {
        "text" : "You go to sleep. You are awoken by the sound of glass smashing outside your house. The time on your alarm reads 12:30AM",
        "nextPart" : "part3"
    },
    "part3" : {
        "text" : "You sit down and start watching TV. All channels seem to be the same thing, a breaking news report. You tune in.",
        "nextPart" : "part4"
    },
    "part4" : 
        {
            "text" : "The reporter on the screen has a panicked tone, which you seem to think is unprofessional. You are horrified by what you hear; people are turning into disgusting deformed mutants that possess super human abilities. You are interrupted by someone jumping through your front window. How rude.",
            "nextPart" : "part5"
        },
    "part5" : {
        "text" : "You get up from your sofa and go towards the dickhead who jumped through your window. He turns out to be a dead body that was acutally thrown through the window. He's missing an eye and large portion of his skull. You look up to see a disfigured man standing outside your window. His face has swollen to 3x it's original size and covers his neck. He climbs through your window. You noticed acidic green liquid dripping from orifices on his face.",
        "nextPart" : "part6"
    }
}

var partObject:Object;
// The first loop gives us an access to "part objects",
// which exists inside of the main object
for(var propName:String in object)
{
    partObject = object[propName];
    // For getting access to the data inside of "part objects",
    // we need to initiate the second loop
    for(var partObjectPropName:String in partObject)
    {
        trace("partObject[\"" + partObjectPropName + "\"]: " + partObject[partObjectPropName]);
    }
}
```